# How can I check the memory usage differences when using UITableViewCell allocations?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**I've always been told to use :**

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id")`

**instead of**

`let cell = UITableViewCell()`

In order to recycle my `cells` instead of recreating them every time. But how can I check the memory usage to have a comparison? **What tool should I use?**

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: Check this: https://doordash.engineering/2019/05/22/ios-memory-leaks-and-retain-cycle-detection-using-xcodes-memory-graph-debugger/

Answer (score 1):

You can measure using Instruments app and run it using profiling.

[Link](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/)

Apart from this, you can also use XCTest and use measure block to check performance.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure)